# AS3, Flash: How to tell if security settings were remembered?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, webcam, microphone

I'm working on some browser based flash app that uses microphone and camera. I need it to proceed only if user has granted access to the camera. I check if the access is already there, in case user allowed access and checked 'remember' setting. If access is not granted, then it could be two things: user has not been prompted with the dialogue yet or he checked 'remember' and denied access. Is there a way to determine which one of these two is applicable now? Basically, I want to determine an answer to this question: **"Has user remembered to deny access to mic/cam?"**

Comment: AFAIK, It's not possible, but I'll look around in the doc to see if I can dig something. Why do you want to differentiate between these two cases ?

Comment: I need to be able to proceed with the program after the access is there. If user hasn't remembered "deny" option - a prompt will appear after I try to access microphone and I can listen to microphone StatusEvent.STATUS to determine if access was given or not. If it was remembered to "deny" - no prompt will appear. I can manually summon security settings window, but it will cause StatusEvent.STATUS event right after I click radial option "allow" and not after I close this security window. Besides that if user leaves "deny" and closes the window - no event at all will fire so I won't know it.

Comment: I see. There is no API-supported way to detect the presence of the SecurityPanel, but I think I remember an older post that indicated that Bitmapdata.draw() used in some way generates a SecurityError when the Panel is open. This workaround may still work.

Comment: Too bad... I wish there was a way to invoke the allow/deny dialogue manually, instead of the SecurityPanel...

Answer (score 0):

For microphone, you could check by creating a  microphone class and seeing the `getMicrophone` function returns null: `var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();`

And this taken from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d0f.html:
When your application calls the Microphone.getMicrophone() method, Flash Player displays the Flash Player Settings dialog box, which prompts the user to either allow or deny Flash Player access to the camera and microphone on the system. After the user clicks on either the Allow button or the Deny button in this dialog, a StatusEvent is dispatched. The code property of that StatusEvent instance indicates whether microphone access was allowed or denied, as shown in this example:

```
import flash.media.Microphone; 

var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(); 
mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, this.onMicStatus); 

function onMicStatus(event:StatusEvent):void 
{ 
    if (event.code == "Microphone.Unmuted") 
    { 
        trace("Microphone access was allowed."); 
    }  
    else if (event.code == "Microphone.Muted") 
    { 
         trace("Microphone access was denied."); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work, Doorhandle, as I described - I'm trying to determine the situation where user has "remembered" to deny access. In this case there will be no allow/deny popup and no StatusEvent.STATUS since there's no change.